# Require node.js module in an internal typescript module

Tags: node.js, module, typescript

I want to port a a multi-file node.js project to a multiple file Typescript project compiling to a single `.js` by using Typescript internal modules. How I can `require` a node.js module from an internal Typescript module? Here is a sample application:

a.js:

```
var os = require('os')
exports.foo = os.hostname()
```

b.js:

```
var os = require('os')
exports.foo = os.hostname()
```

How do I port the code to Typescript?

I have no problems until I want to require:

a.ts:

```
/// <reference path="b.ts" />
console.log(b.foo)
```

b.ts:

```
module b {
    export var foo = 42;
}
```

How do I change the code so `foo = os.hostname()` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot mix `--out` with `--module` at the moment. TypeScript does not give an error the but the generated javascript is wrong

Comment: The issue is closed. You should redesign the example so it has internal modules.

Comment: Its closed because its a duplicate of a feature request : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/759 they are basically saying it is not supported at the moment.